# Using Amazon API Gateway as a proxy for DynamoDB without Lambda . AJAX to make GET request does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am Using Amazon API Gateway as a proxy for DynamoDB without Lambda. My Invoke URL has a path variable {selectdate}. 
I am following the tutorial : 
 https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

> https:// *api url* /prod/dgmvisit3/{selectdate}

I tried the following code to perform a GET request from my webpage but I am not sure If you can do it this way.The TEST on the AWS console for this API works

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//AJAX function
    function startAjax() {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "https://api url/prod/dgmvisit3/{selectdate}",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
             "selectdate" : "13-Nov-18"
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          json = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(json));  
        },
        error: function(){
          console.log("failure");
        }
      });
    }



</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick='startAjax();'>Test</button>  
<!-- <button>Update Select Date</button>  -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem you got? Any specific error messages?

Comment: JSBin editor gives me error message:    XHR finished loading: GET "https:// api url  /prod/dgmvisit3/%7Bselectdate%7D?selectdate=13-Nov-18".

Comment: Does `$.ajax()` support this kind of interpolation?  It doesn't appear to.

Comment: JSbin editor also gave me a HTTP 500 GET error

Comment: $.ajax() may not support it but what else can you use ? There is documentation for   $.ajax GET method,  api gateway , and lambda calling dynamodb. What is the point of the blog if you can't use  GET from a web page with a path variable ?

Comment: This should be simpler than I originally thought. I have output in my browser with the URL https://api url/prod/dgmvisit3/3-Nov-18 from above. All I need to do now is use XMLHttpRequest from javascript to get the output.